# I am using the pgAdmin import utility and get the following error The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

I use windows 10 and postgres with pgAdmin - 4 
this is the running command in the process watcher

"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v1\runtime\\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\"\psql.exe" --command " "\copy public.patients (id, patient_last_name, patients_first_name, patient_mid_initial, patient_telephone, patient_birth_date, patient_sex, patient_account_number, inserted_at, updated_at) FROM 'c://PATIENT.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';""

Start time: Fri Apr 14 2017 16:56:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.